# Python assign local value to attribute in imported module

Tags: python, import, scope, namespaces

In Script1 I've defined class1.

To initiate class1, you just need one variable x, but it has other attribute `y` which is not required to initiate the class. When I run script 1, it assigns value 10 to y which is declared after `if __name__ == __main__:` line.

```
######Script1#########
Class class1:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = 10
    class_instance = class1(100)
    print(class_instance.y) #prints 10 or assigns 10 to class.y
```

In script2 I import class1 and try to assign value to `y`, but it gives me `NameError`. 
I tried declaring y as global in class1, and few other things but it is not working.
I understand it has something to do with namespace and scoping - any pointer in right direction will be of great help. Thanks.

```
#### script2 ######
from script1 import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = 10
    class_instance = class1(200)
    print(class_instance.y) #gives NameError
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want here is an optional `keyword argument` (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
Class class1:
    def __init__(self,x, y=10):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
if __name__ == '__main__':
    class_instance = class1(100)
    print(class_instance.y)              #prints 10 

    instance2 = class1(100,200)
    print(instance2.y)                   #prints 200 

    instance3 = class1(100,y=300)
    print(instance3.y)                   #prints 300
```

This will allow you to supply the `y` value if you wish.  If you do not supply the `y` value, it will use the default of `10`.